# json-simple Java: where's error and how to solve?

Tags: java, json-simple

I have long json answer, here it is:

```
{"head":{},"def":[{"text":"hello","pos":"noun","ts":"?he?l??","tr":[{"text":"привет","pos":"noun","syn":[{"text":"приветствие","pos":"noun","gen":"ср"}],"mean":[{"text":"hi"},{"text":"welcome"}],"ex":[{"text":"big hello","tr":[{"text":"большой привет"}]}]}]},{"text":"hello","pos":"verb","ts":"?he?l??","tr":[{"text":"поздороваться","pos":"verb","asp":"сов","mean":[{"text":"greet"}]}]}]}
```

As you can see, there are some inner massives and I can't get them out! I could only get "def" key, but I get get, for example, "tr" or "mean".

I found code here, that can be useful for me:

```
public static void doJson(String link) throws ParseException {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(link);
    String died = (String) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jj.get("def")).get("tr")).get("text");
    System.out.println(died);
}
```

But it gives me back an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
at StringOfTrans.doJson(StringOfTrans.java:50)
at StringOfTrans.main(StringOfTrans.java:19)
```

So, I thinkm that's right way, but I need to fix it. How can I do it? I want to work with json-simple and that's my first experience with JSON. So, I've read already how to get objects from JSON if it contains only one array, but I can't find good examples with json-simple for parse inner arrays. Thank you!

Comment: `jj.get("def")` gives you an object of type `JSONArray`, so don't cast it to `JSONObject`, cast it to `JSONArray` and work with it as with a `JSONArray`. Particularly, you won't be able to access anything in it by name (`...get("tr")`), you should first pick a `JSONObject` from that array.

Comment: So, can you show me example? First I get JSONArray jj1=  jj.get("def") and the I should create JSONObject = jj1.get("tr"), and the create String or Array for "text" from "tr" or "mean" array?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the structure of JSON you can get the value of the "text" like this:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(link);
JSONArray  def = (JSONArray) jj.get("def");
JSONObject tr  = (JSONObject) def.get(0);
String text = (String) tr.get("text"); //value is hello
```

You should see that "def" actually is a `JSONArray` object. You should change the code to get different nodes with `"text"` values as you need, this is just an example to show you that you will recieve `JSONArray` objects along the way. If for some reason you would want to get the `mean` array. You would just repeat the stept in the code above as this would apply to any other element in the json file.

```
JSONArray trArr = (JSONArray) tr.get("tr");
JSONObject meanNode = (JSONObject) trArr.get(0);
JSONArray meanArr = (JSONArray) meanNode.get("mean");
```

The only difficulty here is to identify your JSON structure to understand whether you will have an array or an object.

Comment: And can I get "mean" massive with this method?

Comment: Yes, you would just need to get the "tr" JSONArray out of the "tr" object   and get the JsonObject out of it which has a JSONArray named "mean" in it.